# How to count the number of two events over a period of time?

Tags: esper

Here are two events:AppStartEvent and AppCrashEvent.
I need to count the number of two events over a period of time, and then to calculate the count(AppStartEvent)/count(AppCrashEvent).

My EPL is here

```
create context ctx4NestInCR 
context ctx4Time initiated @now and pattern [every timer:interval(1 minute)] terminated after 15 minutes, 
context ctx4AppName partition by appName from AppStartEvent, appName from AppCrashEvent
<------------------->
context ctx4NestInCR select count(s),count(c) from AppStartEvent as s, AppCrashEvent as c output last when terminated
```

And it does not work

```
Error starting statement: Joins require that at least one view is specified for each stream, no view was specified for s
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post doesn't have the join? It only has the context and that wouldn't produce the message. I would suggest to correct the post.

You can also join streams by merging the two streams and treating them as one.

```
insert into AppEvent select 'crash' as condition from AppCrashEvent;
insert into AppEvent select 'start' as condition from AppStartEvent;
select count(condition='crash')/count(condition='start') from AppEvent;
```

Comment: Nice way!  I have added the select clause,  do you think is there room for improvement?

Comment: Joins of streams require data windows and the query doesn't specify any

Comment: But I declared a `context ctx4Time` for 15 minutes, why it can not be considered as a time window.